# Work out number of days using Month Calendar Delphi

Tags: delphi, monthcalendar

I'm using two Month calendar on my form. I select a date on each one and I want to calculate the number of days between these two days. I only code I have is

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
 N, m: TDate;
 d: Real;
 l,k:String;
begin
 N := (MonthCalendar1.Date);
 m := MonthCalendar2.Date;
 L := formatdatetime('dd', N);
 K:=formatdatetime('dd',M);
 d := StrToFloat(L)-StrToFloat(K);
 ShowMessage(FloatToStr(d));

end;
```

Comment: You don't need a MonthCalendar to do this.  The part of a TDateTime to the RHS of the decimal point is effectively a "day number" so if you substract one of those from another, you find the "days between".  Apply a Trunc to both to discard the time-of-day parts ...

Comment: Could you please show me in code

Comment: If D1 and D2 are two TDateTimes (that you could enter if you wish using a TMonthCalendar), then DaysBetween := D2 - D1.  I wil post an answer based on this in a few minutes.

Answer (score 5):

You can use DaysBetween() from System.DateUtils to obtain the difference, in days, between two TDateTime values.

See Docs: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.DateUtils.DaysBetween

**Edit**, see code:

```
uses System.DateUtils;
```

[..]

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  NumDays: Integer;    
begin
  NumDays := DaysBetween(MonthCalendar1.Date, MonthCalendar2.Date);     
  ShowMessage('Days between selected dates: ' + NumDays.ToString);    
end;
```

Comment: I prefer this solution, mainly because it makes the code more readable. (And, in some cases, these functions might protect against numerical issues.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a MonthCalendar to do this. The part of a TDateTime to the RHS of the decimal point is effectively a "day number" so if you substract one of those from another, you find the "days between". Apply a Trunc to both to discard the time-of-day parts.  See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.TDateTime for definition of TDateTime.

So, for example, given

```
var
  D1,
  D2 : TDateTime;
  DaysBetween : Integer;
```

and D1 and D2 are two TDateTimes (that you could enter if you wish using a TMonthCalendar), then

```
  DaysBetween := Trunc(D2) - Trunc(D1);
```

The call to the built-in `Trunc` function discards the fractional, time-of-day part of a TDateTime value (that is, the partr to the right of the decimal point), so that 23:59 on one day and 00:01 on the next are calculated to be one day apart.  This may, or may not, be the result you want, depending on your application, which is why I have suggested calculating it yourself rather than using the built-in DaysBetween function.